# Getting "required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input 'Scenario:'" error when using Background section in cucumber

Tags: cucumber, bdd, karate

I am writing a Karate DSL test to test a web service end point. I have defined my url base in karate-config.js file already. But when I try to use this in the Background section, I am getting the below error. Please help. Provided my feature file below.

Error: "required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input 'Scenario:'"

```
Feature: Test Data Management service endpoints that perform different operations with EPR

    Background:
     url dataManagementUrlBase

    Scenario: Validate that the contractor's facility requirements are returned from EPR
    Given path 'facilities'
    And def inputpayload = read('classpath:dataManagementPayLoad.json')
    And request inputpayload
    When method post
    Then status 200
    And match $ == read('classpath:dataManagementExpectedJson.json')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `*` before the `url`

```
Background:
* url dataManagementUrlBase
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. For some reasons, even though I add a * before the url, the error does not go right away. But If I close and re-open eclipse, this error is no longer displaying. And again whenever I do any changes with the Background, this keeps coming back. As of now, solving this by closing and re-opening eclipse. Not sure why this keeps coming back when changes were made to Background.

Comment: The * could be replaced with any of the keywords Given, When, Then, And, But. Doing so may give you something that is easier to read.