# Why am I getting the following error: "required(..)+ loop did not match anything at input Scenario:" after the Background section in my feature file?

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, karate

No errors appear in the feature file when I am not having "Background:" section. But when I add a background section above my scenarios in feature file, I am getting this error in eclipse IDE before the first scenario. My feature files goes as follows:

Feature: Greeting end-point
Background:
* baseUrl 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
Scenario: Default greeting

```
Given url baseUrl
When method get
Then status 200
And print response
```

I have attached a screenshot just in case that might help u in providing assistance[image]

Comment: Yes, I have marked them as accepted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make this change. I have tested this and it is working fine. If you have used the wrong version of the Cucumber Eclipse plugin, please refer here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/90

Make sure you are using the latest version of Karate (0.6.2 as of today).

If all of that fails, use a [JUnit runner](https://github.com/intuit/karate#running-with-junit):

```
Background: 
* def baseUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' 

Scenario: Default greeting
    Given url baseUrl
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And print response
```

Comment: I have tried it and still get the same error. In fact, I have just replicated many examples you have posted in answers here, but I face a problem when I have a background section.

Comment: I find a similar issue here -    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46816265/getting-required-loop-did-not-match-anything-at-input-scenario-error. I dont think the issue got resolved for him too after reading for comments.

Comment: @VimalRaj please be polite and don't make it sound like it is my fault. If you are not willing to read the documentation and use the latest / proper versions of Karate and the Eclipse plugin, you will face all these issues. I have edited the answer. AND It would be good if you up-vote answers also instead of just accepting them.

Comment: I am new to this community and hence sometimes forget to upvote the answers.

In the comment, I referred to the other issue not in any way to offend you, but to provide more insight so it might be of any use. If any rudeness is percieved, please consider it as a beginner's mistake. You are doing a great job helping people here and why would I want to be rude? :)